# grab url from url bar using javascript or php

Tags: javascript

I'm working with an API that uses OAuth implicitly. It redirects to the URL http://exmaple.com/#access_token=38927491.4d15ef2.d4769148101a4a70a201c1c40b8acc40

How do I grab this via JavaScript , or PHP ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, `window.location.href` will give you the url of the current page.

to get the access token, do like so:

```
window.location.hash.match("access_token=([^&]*)")[1]
```

Comment: s=window.location.href;
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('#'));

Comment: this is what i got and still nothing , i really appreciate this , `Copy and paste code from This page into the code box on the homepage and go claim your likes!!!<br>

Your code is 
<script>
window.location.hash.match("access_token=([^&]*)")[1];

</script>`

Comment: hmm.  not entirely sure where to go from here.  i'm not sure how you're exercising this code.  perhaps you can use Chrome dev tools or the like to try running this code in the console.  Or add an `alert()` with either/both the above code snips in it; it's possible your issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

Comment: this is what i put for it but it didnt work ...                 `Copy and paste code from This page into the code box on the homepage and go claim your likes!!!<br>

Your code is 
<script>
var hash = window.location.hash;

</script>`

Comment: Nonsense, this code does exactly what u need. Perhaps your testing tools are preventing this from working ?